# Using vbscript to call .NET getter and setter properties returning objects

Tags: .net, com, vbscript

I have a C# assembly which has methods and getters/setters. I can call the method in the comvisible C# assembly from vb6, but the getter/setter is failing with error - 'Object doesn't support this property or method'

For Example, my class in .net assembly is like this:

```
public class Test{
 SubMain _subMain;
    public Test()
    {
        _subMain = new SubMain();
    }

 public string Dump(){ return "test"; }

 public SubMain SubMain
    {
        get
        {
            return _subMain;
        }
    }

public class SubMain
{
    public SubMain()
    {
    }

    public string Dump()
    {
        return "SubMain";
    }
}

---- 
vbscript:

Set obj = CreateObject("SampleCSForCOM.Main")
str = obj.Dump()
wscript.echo "method string="+str
wscript.echo "property string="+obj.SubMain.Dump()

----
Error in vbscript:
C:\test>cscript test.vbs
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

method string=Main
C:\test\test.vbs(4, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object doesn't support
this property or method: 'obj.SubMain'
```

Question:
If I use a property which returns a string, it works well in vbscript. But, if I use a property which returns another object, it is failing.

Comment: is this vbscript or vb6 ?

Comment: You might also post your VB code.

Comment: It is vbscript and I just added vb code. Updated with the correct repro.

Comment: OK, to answer my question. If I change the property name from SubMain to something else like SubMainProperty, then I do not see the issue anymore.